# MySQL select table

Tags: mysql, url

How can I select a MySQL table when the table name is in the URL format?

```
SELECT hash FROM 'http://www.mittelbayerische.de' WHERE time = '1465132682'
```

This will output following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''http://www.mittelbayerische.de' WHERE time = '1465132682'' at line 1
```

Comment: That's a string. You could use `SELECT * FROM 'user3806126';` It would generate the same error. If that really is your table name, you can use '`' instead. But seriously consider revising your naming policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that's a table name?

Anyway assuming it is, you should be able to use backticks to quote the table name.

```
SELECT hash FROM `http://www.mittelbayerische.de` WHERE time = '1465132682'
```